# Send email through symfony 3 form

Tags: symfony

I tried the documentation on swiftmailer symfony [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html) but I can't make it work even though it all seems correct to me.

I changed the paramaters.yml and didn't touch the config.yml as explained.
It seems that the error comes from my controller, but in case I will copy you the code I have been writing/changing:

**parameters.yml**

```
    parameters:
        //
        mailer_host: localhost
        mailer_user: mymail@gmail.com
        mailer_password: mypassword
```

**config.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```

**my form**

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('mail', EmailType::class, array(
                'label' => 'your mail'
            ))
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'your message'
            ))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'    => Contact::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

**My controller**

```
    class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $contact = new Contact();
        $formContact = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
        $formContact->handleRequest($request);
        $data = $formContact->getData();


        if ($formContact->isSubmitted() && $formContact->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($contact);
            $em->flush();

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
            $message->setFrom($data->getMail())
                ->setTo('mymail@gmail.com')
                ->setBody($data->getMessage() . $data->getMail());

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        }

        return $this->render('app/main/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $formContact->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

An here is the error when I run this code
[image]

I don't know if it helps or if you need more informatio but would be glad to share, thank you.

Comment: Seems like the error explains it quite well. Your trying to access a property called mail on your `Contact` class object thingy. But since its private you can only access it from within that class (entity). Use/ create the getter/setter (adviced) if they are generated (`$data->getMail()`) or make it public in the entity (not recommended) `->getData()` returns the class you specified in the createForm

Comment: thanks for the reply @JenneVanDerMeer I updated my question and added your advice. I don't get any error now, but I don't receive any emails, is there anything else in my code that is wrong? (the mail and password is good)

Comment: @JennevanderMeer thank you by the way for your help, I succeeded in receiving one email :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify Jenne's point: You need to use a getter method to access a private variable.

However, you're also using a `spool` in your config, so you need to actually access and fire off the spool once you've queued up a message. (See: [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html)). If you don't want to spool, remove that line from your config, and emails should be sent directly from the code (Like shown in the [tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html)).

Comment: Hi @Darkstarone I succeeded at sending an email ! although I had to 'hack' to be able to see the email of the sender. I couldn't make it work, any idea on how that works? (check the updated controller at the line `->setBody($data->getMessage() . $data->getMail());` )

Comment: Hmm, you mean you couldn't see the sender in your email client? That could be a client side issue - I'm afraid I don't actually have much experience with `swiftmailer`, so I wouldn't know!

Comment: Since you're sending from a gmail account, you may want to look at [this](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email/gmail.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128472/how-to-set-from-property-using-swiftmailer-with-gmail) - Gmail blocks some swiftmailer options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try to get that to work. At the moment I had to let my gmail accept mails from less protected website and put the line I just told you to see the mail sender.

Comment: Good luck - remember to accept the question if I've answered your initial question satisfactorily - as it stops other users from attempting to answer. If you're still having trouble with the gmail sender, I would advice starting another question.